# Sending JSON using $http cause angular to send text/plain content type

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, tastypie

I just want to send the following JSONobjects to my API backend:

```
{
    "username":"alex",
    "password":"password"
}
```

So I wrote the following function, using Angular $http:

```
$http(
{
    method: 'POST', 
    url: '/api/user/auth/',
    data: '{"username":"alex", "password":"alex"}',
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
 // Do Stuff
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
 // Do Stuff
});
```

I read in documentation for POST method that Content-Type header will be automatically set to **"application/json"**.

But I realized that the content-type I receive on my backend (Django+Tastypie) api is **"text/plain"**.

This cause my API to not respond properly to this request. How should I manage this content-type?

Comment: How your backend is retrieving the details?

Comment: I use Django Tastypie for my Backend. I see text/plain in content type sending by $http. raw_post_data or POST data is also empty.

Comment: So strange... If I put headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'} it is working.. But if I put application/json... it's not...

Comment: I'm also seeing this behavior.  When the data block is empty it seems that Angular is ignoring the default "application/json" and setting the Content-Type to "plain/text".

Neither explicitly setting the default on $http nor setting the Content-Type as an argument to the put() call seems to have any effect.

I am using AngularJS 1.2.0.

Comment: Are you setting headers through configuration phase?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've moved forward with is to always initialize models on the $scope to an empty block {} on each controller.  This guarantees that if no data is bound to that model then you will still have an empty block to pass to your $http.put or $http.post method.

```
myapp.controller("AccountController", function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {}; // Guarantee $scope.user will be defined if nothing is bound to it

    $scope.saveAccount = function() {
        users.current.put($scope.user, function(response) {
            $scope.success.push("Update successful!");
        }, function(response) {
            $scope.errors.push("An error occurred when saving!");
        });
    };
}

myapp.factory("users", function($http) {
    return {
        current: {
            put: function(data, success, error) {
                return $http.put("/users/current", data).then(function(response) {
                    success(response);
                }, function(response) {
                    error(response);
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Another alternative is to use the binary || operator on data when calling $http.put or $http.post to make sure a defined argument is supplied:

```
$http.put("/users/current", data || {}).then(/* ... */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

$http.post('/api/user/auth/', data).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
 // Do Stuff
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
 // Do Stuff
});
```